# i can't upgrade qgis 2.4 some error on depends not be solved

Tags: 14.04

How to solve this?

```
python-qgis: Depends: python-qgis-common (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
             Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
             Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.7 (>= 2.7) but 2.7.6-8 is to be installed
             Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
             Depends: libspatialite3 (>= 2.4.0~rc2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
             Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: python (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.5-5ubuntu3 is to be installed
             Depends: sip-api-8.1 but it is not going to be installed
qgis: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.2.2) but 3.4.2-4ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.6.1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libqt4-sql (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
      Depends: libspatialite3 (>= 2.4.0~rc2) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.0) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
      Depends: qgis-providers (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
      Depends: qgis-common (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
qgis-plugin-globe: Depends: qgis (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
                   Depends: qgis-plugin-globe-common (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libopenscenegraph80 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libosgearth1 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqt4-opengl (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
qgis-plugin-grass: Depends: qgis (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
                   Depends: qgis-plugin-grass-common (= 2.4.0+precise1) but 2.4.0+precise1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgdal1-1.7.0 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libqt4-svg (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: grass641 but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: could you specify the command that you run?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem which was solved by following these instructions from the qgis installers page:

**Via ubuntugis:**

The ubuntugis project provides newer versions of various FOSSGIS packages, QGIS being one of them.

Current packages available for precise and saucy.

If you want to use those packages, remove the `http://qgis.org/debian` lines from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and upgrade updated dependencies by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

This worked flawlessly for me. Good luck!